# Realm instance has already been closed - with RxJava2

Tags: android, realm, rx-java2

I used Realm in conjunction with RxJava it this way:

```
public Flowable<List<EventEntity>> getAll() {
  try (final Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(mRealmConfiguration)) {
    RealmQuery<RealmEvent> query = realm.where(RealmEvent.class);
    Flowable<RealmResults<RealmEvent>> result;
    if (realm.isAutoRefresh()) {
       result = query
       .findAllAsync()
       .asFlowable()
       .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded);
    } else {
      result = Flowable.just(query.findAll());
    }
    return result
      .unsubscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
  }
}
```

I use this chain on multiple places in app. For example:

```
return Observable.merge(
      mEventRepository.getAll()
        .toObservable(),
      subjectNotificationChange
        .flatMapMaybe(notification ->
          mEventRepository.getAll()
            .firstElement()
        )
    )
```

Problem is that I obtain exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable.

I looked at implementation method from of RealmObservableFactory and each call of subscribe method should create new instance of Realm. Entire situation looks as problem with references counting.

Do you know where is problem?

Comment: Do you call `realm.close()` anywhere else manually?

Comment: No. When I omit try with resources than all works correctly.

Comment: This is really strange to me because based on the code, I'd expect this to work... :(

Comment: Okay, wait, hold on. Are you sure you're not getting that error on a background thread? Because the `.just()` side won't work if Realm is closed with no other instance open for the thread.

Comment: Adding the exception stack trace could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's `try-with-resource` closes the resource **as soon as you leave the code block**, but RxJava being **lazy** and all, only begins working when you actually subscribe, which happens after your code exits the `getAll()` function.

Edit: since you build a special `Realm` instance each time, passing configuration to it, the instance is not shared and therefore definitively closed each time.

Instead, initialize your `Realm` earlier using `Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)`. Then, use `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` in your function so you access the default shared instance instead of creating a new one each time.

Edit2: the easiest solution is to keep a reference to the `Realm` instance:

```
class MyRepository {

    private final Realm realm;

    public MyRepository(Realm realm) {
        this.realm = realm;
    }

    public Flowable<List<EventEntity>> getAll() {
        RealmQuery<RealmEvent> query = realm.where(RealmEvent.class);
        // ...
    }

}

Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
MyRepository repository = MyRepository(realm);
repository.getAll()
// ...
```

Comment: Yes, but implementation of subscribe method again call getInstance method of Realm. When Realm instance is closed than RealmResult is destroyed?

Comment: @elnino sorry if I wasn't clear enough. You request a `Realm` instance, prepare a `Flowable` and return it. The problem is that as you return it, that `Realm` instance gets closed by the `try-with`. So when you subscribe later, the initial `Realm` reference that you had got closed and is no longer valid. And yes, results from a `Realm` instance are invalidated when you close the instance.

Comment: I watched this solution (try with resources) on official page of  Realm. At bottom of page.
https://academy.realm.io/posts/creating-a-reactive-data-layer-with-realm-and-rxjava2/
Can solve this problem use of defer? Object can be created and subscribed before auto close of Realm. Or is better solution used Realm without closing instance?

Comment: @elnino I think that I see the problem now: you are creating a special `Realm` instance passing configuration to it, instead of requesting the default instance. Try configuring your `Realm` earlier with `Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)` and using `getDefaultInstance()` in your code.

Comment: I used getDefaultInstance but result is same,

Comment: @elnino then it is likely that you don't have any other reference open, so the underlying instance gets closed. See the code example I have added for a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution. It is **bug in official example**. When you call mentioned chain than **must exist other open Realm instance for same thread**. In other cases RealmResult is invalidated. Can be used solution mentioned by *ESala*.